# The apostrophe and backslash paradox

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

I've been puzzling with this for a while now, and have finally succumb to asking for help here.

I have a preg_match script for scraping, that matches different variables in a loop and stores them in an array, to finally be posted into a SQL table. The problem occurs whenever a variable contains an apostrophe.

Here's how I grab and organize the data

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($bokse[0]); $i++){
    preg_match_all("/title=\"Mere information om (.+?)\"/sim", $bokse[0][$i], $name, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    $laeger[$i]['navn'] = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($name[0][1]));
}
```

Now, the value of something that I grabbed, mysql_escaped and stripped can be:

```
**Michael D'Angelo** [NOTICE THE APOSTROPHE]
```

If I want to echo this to the page, I can succesfully echo `D'angelo` correctly (with apostrophe)

```
echo $laeger[$i]['navn'];
```

Will give me `Michael D'Angelo`.

But when it comes to storing this in a database, I run into a paradox; I can chose to either store it as `Michael D\'Angelo`

Or store the D, and receive an SQL error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'angelo'
(..........blablabv...............)
```

Here's how I store the data

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES ('".$laeger[$i]['navn']."'")");  or die(mysql_error());
```

Depending on if I stripslashes or not, I'll either mess up the query or mess up the result (with a bachflash). FML.

Comment: `stripslashes` undoes what `mysql_real_escape_string` did. That's why the output is unescaped and unfit for SQL string context later.

Comment: I don't think you understand what a paradox is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted in your comment, the accepted answer does nothing for you. It will only work if you know in advance what data you are going to be scraping so you can put the backslashes in the correct place, but of course you do not know in advance so you need a solution that will work at run time. MySQL provides such a solution for you.

The answer that solves your issue is to change your insert to:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($laeger[$i]['navn'])."'")");
```

Or as I prefer to do it, even though it is non-standard:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO table set name='".mysql_real_escape_string($laeger[$i]['navn'])."'");
```

I think that it is much easier to code and much easier to read.

For my own work, I created a "helper function" named "dbstring" that wraps the apostrophes around the escape function which makes everything even more compact, more readable, transportable between databases and SQL injection attack resistant.

Comment: Or perhaps a parameterized query?

Answer (score 5):

There is no paradox. You're just not understanding how escaping works.

If you have:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (fieldname) VALUES ('Michael D\'Angelo')
```

That backslash will **NOT** get entered into the database's on-disk storage. It's stripped out by the database's SQL parser. Similarly, it will NOT be escaped when you retrieve the name from the table. You'll get `Michael D'Angelo` returned to your client.

What you have is an SQL injection attack vulnerability - allowing raw user-provided data that contains SQL metacharacters to appear in an SQL context without accounting for those metacharacters.

That's why there's (for old-school code) things like `mysql_real_escape_string()` which escapes all SQL metacharacters in the provided string, so they become plaintext and no longer "meta".

Comment: So the most rationel solution to this would be what? I'm a little baffled by how the escaping doesnt translate into the echoed.

Comment: treat escaping like wrapping a present. the wrapping prevents the present from being "seen" until it reaches the recipient. once it does, it's unwrapped and used. the wrapping is thrown away by the user. so  `Michael D\'Angelo` is "wrapped" for the database. It unwraps and stores `Michael D'Angelo` in the actual data files. Once that `'` is actually stored in the db, it can no longer "break" the query statement, because the database KNOWS that it's part of the string, and not an sql meta character.